# I'm trying to write a code in which the character "|" is inbetween each letter however it does not work for some characters

Tags: python

I have written the code below in which each after each letter there will be a `|`:

```
def art(word):
    numoflet = len(word)
    word = word.upper()

    for Y in range(numoflet - 1, 0, -1):
        if word[Y:].count(word[Y]) >= 2:
            pass
        else:
            let = word[Y]
            let1 = let + "|"
            word = word.replace(let, let1)

    word = "|" + word
    pat = ""

    numoflet = len(word)
    for X in range(numoflet, 0, -1):
        if X % 2 == 0:
            pat = pat + "-"
        else:
            pat = pat + "+"

    print("\n" + pat + "\n\n" + word + "\n\n" + pat)

word = "Craig'n'Dave"
art(word)
```

My intended output is;

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

|C|R|A|I|G|'|N|'|D|A|V|E|

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

However after some letters (C, N, D below) it does not produce the `|` shown in the result below:

```
-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

|CR|A|I|G|'|N'|DA|V|E|

-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You're updating `word` while iterating over it, which probably is resulting in skipping some elements. Have you tried making another variable equal to `word` initially, and then modifying _that_ while iterating over `word`?

Comment: Did you know `"|".join(word)` would work as an alternative to your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions; it has really helped with the troubleshooting, and the problem in general, and I managed to fix it, so it is all good.

Here is my finished code:

```
def art(word):
  numoflet=len(word)
  word=word.upper()
  for Y in range(numoflet-1,-1,-1):
    let=word[Y]
    let1=let+"|"
    word=word[:Y]+word[Y].replace(let,let1)+word[Y+1:]
    print(word)
    print(Y)
  word="|"+word
  pat=""
  numoflet=len(word)
  for X in range(numoflet,0,-1):
    if X%2==0:
      pat=pat+"-"
    else:
      pat=pat+"+"
  print("\n"+pat+"\n\n"+word+"\n\n"+pat)
#maincode
art("Craig'n'Dave")
```

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons your routine is not doing what you expect.

1. replace() replaces all occurrences, so when you replace the A in DAVE you are also replacing the A in CRAIG, which really messes things up.
2. Your range is not including the first letter "C". The "stop" parameter is not included in the range.

During debugging a well placed "print()" can help you solve your problem. If you print(Y) each time through the loop you will see that the loop stops when Y=1, instead of when Y=0.

If you print(word) each time through the loop you will see the error when the loop handles the A.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join method that join list of string with another string.
First `list("Craig'n'Dave")` create `['C', 'r', 'a', 'i', 'g', "'", 'n', "'", 'D', 'a', 'v', 'e']`  then you join each elements with `"|"`

```
word="Craig'n'Dave"
def art(word, title_rep="+-", sep="|"):
    result = sep.join(list(word)).upper()
    head = title_rep * (len(result) // len(title_rep)) + title_rep[:len(result) % len(title_rep)]
    return f"{head}\n{result}\n{head}"

print(art(word))
```

Output:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+                                                                                                 
C|R|A|I|G|'|N|'|D|A|V|E                                                                                                 
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Comment: But why do they get a different result?

Comment: btw `head` can be reduced to `head = ''.join(char for _, char in zip(result, cycle(tuple(title_rep))))` but then you also need to `from itertools import cycle`

Comment: Nice! I will check that and update answer